# How to get column names from SQLAlchemy result (declarative syntax)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, pyramid

I am working in a pyramid project and I've the table in SQLAlchemy in declarative syntax

```
"""models.py"""
class Projects(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
```

I get the results by using

```
""""views.py"""
session = DBSession()
row_data = session.query(Projects).filter_by(id=1).one()
```

How can I get the column names from this result.

PS: I am unable to use [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg02188.html) method since I am using the declarative syntax.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The difference is between ORM and non-ORM, not declarative, which is just a helper for the ORM.

Query has an attribute `column_descriptions` that was added for this purpose:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.column_descriptions

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately, this returns
    [{'aliased': False, 'expr': <class 'metrics.models.Projects'>, 'type': <class 'metrics.models.Projects'>, 'name': 'Projects'}]
I am trying to use reflection so that I don't have to specify the column name and with this method I'll still have to specify the column names. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think I found the solution. I was able to get the column list by using Projects.__table__.columns.keys()

Comment: I think this only works if you are specifying which columns you want back in the query (which means you already know the column names). What @Sukumar and I need is the columns for a query constructed like `q=sess.query(MyTableObject).all()`

Answer (score 85):

You can do something similar to Foo Stack's answer without resorting to private fields by doing:

```
conn.execute(query).keys()
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but hoping someone knows: if the query is for more than one entity, how do you get unambiguous column names?  For a query like `Query(DataClass1).join(DataClass2).add_entity(DataClass2)`, if `DataClass1` and `DataClass2` have fields with the same names, then `keys()` returns a list with duplicate entries.

Answer (score 79):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Index, Date, DateTime, Numeric, BigInteger, String, ForeignKey, Boolean)

Base = declarative_base()

class Project(Base):
    """sqlalchemy ORM for my table."""
    __tablename__ = "table1"
    id = Column("id", BigIntegerID, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    date = Column("date", Date, nullable=False)
    value = Column("value", Numeric(20, 8))
    ...
    ...
```

Then this will return the columns names ['id', 'date', 'value', ...]:

```
Project.__table__.columns.keys()
```

Or this

```
Project.metadata.tables['table1'].columns.keys()
```

Comment: Note that 'columns' is interchangeable with 'c', so for above Project.metadata.tables[Project.__tablename__].c.keys() would also work. As would Project.__table__.c.keys()

Answer (score 15):

Just playing around, this syntax will give you all the columns (so to solve your problem, set query to look at one table/object only):

```
conn.execute(query)._metadata.keys
```

Comment: its still there 5 years later. Only way you can make something reliable is to rely on that.

Comment: Nice! It'll be useful in a property (setter) method

Answer (score 12):

**Short answer** is that I ended up with the following solution:

```
column_names = query.statement.columns.keys()
```

**Why?**

I had a similar use case where I need to know the explicit columns returned by a query (i.e., the query does not necessarily contain all columns of a table class). Since the table is also massive in size (millions of entries), [prolibertas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31734636/3162788) answer was not satisfying in terms of performance. Here a performance comparison on my table with 94 columns:

```
# First create a query with 100.000 entries
query = (
            session.query(myTable)
            .limit(100000)
        )

# Then get the column names .. 

column_names = session.execute(query).keys()
# ---> ~ 5.730 seconds

column_names = query.statement.columns.keys()
# ---> ~ 0.003 seconds
```

Answer (score 7):

This link shows how to get all the metadata you could ever need about a table, column and more.

[SQLAlchemy Metadata](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html)

Many of the answers above are based on the info on this page. 
Suppose we have declared a table.

```
employees = Table('employees', metadata,
    Column('employee_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('employee_name', String(60), nullable=False),
    Column('employee_dept', Integer, ForeignKey("departments.department_id"))
)
```

Here are some examples of getting metadata about the table.

```
# access the column "EMPLOYEE_ID":
employees.columns.employee_id

# or just
employees.c.employee_id

# via string
employees.c['employee_id']

# iterate through all columns
for c in employees.c:
    print(c)

# get the table's primary key columns
for primary_key in employees.primary_key:
    print(primary_key)

# get the table's foreign key objects:
for fkey in employees.foreign_keys:
    print(fkey)

# access the table's MetaData:
employees.metadata

# access the table's bound Engine or Connection, if its MetaData is bound:
employees.bind

# access a column's name, type, nullable, primary key, foreign key
employees.c.employee_id.name
employees.c.employee_id.type
employees.c.employee_id.nullable
employees.c.employee_id.primary_key
employees.c.employee_dept.foreign_keys

# get the "key" of a column, which defaults to its name, but can
# be any user-defined string:
employees.c.employee_name.key

# access a column's table:
employees.c.employee_id.table is employees

# get the table related by a foreign key
list(employees.c.employee_dept.foreign_keys)[0].column.table
```

Comment: bravo! i learned something and didn't just copy

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
>>> q[0].keys()
```

After

```
row_data = session.query(Projects).filter_by(id=1).one()
```

Example :

```
>>> q = session.query(users_user.phone,users_user.first_name).filter(users_user.phone=='79267548577').limit(1).all()
>>> columns_names = q[0].keys
```

Result :

```
>>> q[0].keys()
['phone', 'first_name']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 manual advise to use following lines:

```
colnames = query.statement.subquery().columns.keys()
```

or if you are using "execute" statement:

```
result = session.execute(text("SELECT * from my_table_name"))
print(result.keys())
```

Answer (score -1):

Would like to extend @zzzeek's answer. Indeed Query has `column_descriptions` attribute but it's not available for all the methods.

Consider the following two queries:

```
1. query = session.query(Projects).filter_by(<filter_condition>)
2. query = session.query(Projects).all() <-- This query does not have column_descriptions.
```

So if you come across this situation where you need to use `column_descriptions` attribute but using `...query(...).all()` then you can change it to `...query(...).filter_by()` i.e. `filter_by()` without any filter condition.