# How to get column name from sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Given my models

```
class CUSTOMER():
    ID              =   db.Column(db.String(12), primary_key=True)
    PotentialCustomer   =   db.Column(db.String(12))
    FirstNameEn     =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    LastNameEn      =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    FirstNameKh     =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    LastNameKh      =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    Salutation      =   db.Column(db.String(4))
    Gender          =   db.Column(db.String(6))
    DateOfBirth     =   db.Column(db.String(10))
    CountryOfBirth  =   db.Column(db.String(2))
    Nationality     =   db.Column(db.String(2))
    ProvinceOfBirth =   db.Column(db.String(3))
```

I would like to get a list column name of model `CUSTOMER()` so that I could loop through that column name?

I tried to surfed around via google but has no clue how I can archive that?

Any idea I can archive that? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get column names from SQLAlchemy result (declarative syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455560/how-to-get-column-names-from-sqlalchemy-result-declarative-syntax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are searching for `column_descriptions()`.

When you use `column_descriptions()`, you would get the metadata about the columns which would be returned in the query.

In your case:

```
customer_alias = aliased(CUSTOMER, name='customer2')
#If you want a single field (CUSTOMER.ID)
customer_query = con.query(CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER.ID, customer_alias)
```

## Then, you should use this expresion:

```
customer_query.column_descriptions
```

## The output

```
[
    {
        'name':'CUSTOMER',
        'type':CUSTOMER,
        'aliased':False,
        'expr':CUSTOMER,
        'entity': CUSTOMER
    },
    {
        'name':'ID',
        'type':String(),
        'aliased':False,
        'expr':CUSTOMER.ID,
        'entity': CUSTOMER
    },
    {
        'name':'customer2',
        'type':CUSTOMER,
        'aliased':True,
        'expr':customer_alias,
        'entity': customer_alias
    }
]
```

But, in case you want all the keys, you should:

```
#we just want one field:
query = session.query(CUSTOMER).filter_by(id=1)
#then:
conn.execute(query).keys()
```

And you will get the column names `['id',PotentialCustomer, FirstNameEN...]`

Another options:

```
CUSTOMER.__table__.columns.keys()
CUSTOMER.metadata.columns.keys()
```

Comment: from your example, we can get only one column "ID", how to get all column? Thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun I added this case

Comment: perfect :) I prefer option ```CUSTOMER.__table__.columns.keys()
CUSTOMER.metadata.columns.keys()```. Regards, Thanks so much.

Comment: I had somenthing similar (equivalent) but not works for the command column_descriptions, indeed i gets model name.