# Missing column names when importing data from database (python + postgre sql)

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I am trying to import some data from the database (Postgre SQL) to work with them in Python. I tried with the code below, which seems quite similar to the ones I've found on the internet.

```
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy as db
import pandas as pd

engine = db.create_engine('database specifications')
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData()
data = db.Table(tabela, metadata, schema=shema, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = db.select([data])
ResultProxy = connection.execute(query)
ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(ResultSet)
```

However, it returns data without column names. What did I forget?

Comment: Please include whatever imports are needed to make this work.

Comment: I've edited the code with the libraries needed to make this code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the only thing needed is adding

```
columns = data.columns.keys()
df.columns = columns
```

There is a great debate about that in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455560/how-to-get-column-names-from-sqlalchemy-result-declarative-syntax).