# Python/sqlalchemy/get column names after running SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have an already existing oracle DB, and there are many tables. Each table has hundreds of the columns as such I don't want to define class.
I use below code to create the table object and it seems works as I can print the columns:

```
def get_engine(username, password, db):
    try:
        connection = f"oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@{db}"
        
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection, arraysize=1000)
        return engine
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(e)

engine = get_engine(username = username, password = password, db = db)
Base = declarative_base()
meta = Base.metadata
meta.bind = engine
schema = "beta"

activity = Table('ACTIVITY',
                        meta,
                        autoload=True, 
                         autoload_with=engine,
                        schema=schema 
                        )

stmt = select([
    activity.columns.activity_date, 
    activity.columns.activity_number,
    activity.columns.activity_user
]
).where(and_(
    activity.columns.activity_date== date(2021, 9, 1)
#     ,
#    activity_date.columns.activity_user <> 'Mary George'
))
```

Then - I read the result into a pandas data frame

```
p = pd.DataFrame(results)
connection.close()
```

But i couldn't get the column names from the stmt, or the results.

Can you please shed some lights?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get column names from SQLAlchemy result (declarative syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455560/how-to-get-column-names-from-sqlalchemy-result-declarative-syntax)

Comment: try `p = pd,read_sql_query(stmt, engine)`

Comment: Thanks @hmn Falahi. Yes it also works but combining with Pandas it's easier :)